# OAuth2 Requesting and Storing Token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

This is probably a simple question but I can't seem to wrap my head around on how OAuth2 works.  So I got upto the point where I can request a token and start pulling data in Ruby console.  But after I exit out of Ruby console, I tried requesting data (.rb script) from API again using the same token but it says expired/invalid.  Am I suppose to store this token somewhere permanently like in a database or cookie?

Not sure if this matters but when I request a token, it brings me to the OAuth2 page to allow or deny a token request.  How do you bypass this in Ruby code?  From what I'm reading, you use the `token.refresh!` method?

Can you please share your insights on what I'm not understanding or missing?

Comment: Yes, you are expected to store that token until it expires.

Comment: Any ideas on how you would bypass the part where it takes me to the OAuth page to click on allow or deny token access?  I might be misunderstanding on how this actually works.  If I generate the token once and hard coded it into the script, does it not use that same token and run it the same as if it was in console?  I'm not understanding why exiting out the console will make the token expire/invalid when trying to use it again immediately.

Comment: You cannot 'skip' the permission step. This is something built into the different platforms so that a user can actually log into their own account, and give your application permission to use their account information. The only thing I can think of is the provider is keeping a very short life on the tokens created. This is not normally the case.

Comment: Oh ok, I get what you mean now.  I'll just speak with the guys who manage the API then.  Thanks for helping out!